# What makes a Tree-Structured Parzen Estimator "tree-structured?"

Tags: bayesian, hyperparameter-tuning

From what I understand the Tree-Structured Parzen Estimator (TPE) creates two probability models based on hyperparameters that exceed the performance of some threshold and hyperparameters that don't.

What I don't fully understand is why TPE is "tree-structured." Is the simple clustering of y > thresh and y < thresh sufficient to call it a "tree?" When I envision a "tree structure" I usually think of many different "forks," perhaps some that are not binary and some that are forks of forks. Although a tree with just one fork is still technically a tree, the name "Tree-Structured Parzen Estimator" seems like it would describe something much more complex.

My question is whether or not I am missing some other deeper conceptual "forks" inherent in TPE that would turn it into a "tree" when you look at the bigger picture.

Comment: (Also [later] asked at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/463075/232706.)

Comment: towards a more precise, computer science - level, answer, cf. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/463075/what-is-the-tree-structure-in-tree-parzen-estimators/463585#463585

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that your hyperparameter space is tree-like: the value chosen for one hyperparameter determines what hyperparameter will be chosen next and what values are available for it.

From [a HyperOpt example](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt/wiki/FMin#22-a-search-space-example-scikit-learn), in which the model type is chosen first, and depending on that different hyperparameters are available:

```
space = hp.choice('classifier_type', [
{
    'type': 'naive_bayes',
},
{
    'type': 'svm',
    'C': hp.lognormal('svm_C', 0, 1),
    'kernel': hp.choice('svm_kernel', [
        {'ktype': 'linear'},
        {'ktype': 'RBF', 'width': hp.lognormal('svm_rbf_width', 0, 1)},
        ]),
},
{
    'type': 'dtree',
    'criterion': hp.choice('dtree_criterion', ['gini', 'entropy']),
    'max_depth': hp.choice('dtree_max_depth',
        [None, hp.qlognormal('dtree_max_depth_int', 3, 1, 1)]),
    'min_samples_split': hp.qlognormal('dtree_min_samples_split', 2, 1, 1),
},
])
```

From [the original paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/4443-algorithms-for-hyper-parameter-optimization.pdf):

> In this work we restrict ourselves to tree-structured configuration spaces. Configuration spaces are tree-structured in the sense that some leaf variables (e.g. the number of hidden
>   units in the 2nd layer of a DBN) are only well-defined when node variables (e.g. a discrete choice of how many layers to use) take particular values.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can't give you the perfect answer since I am still working on the details about the algorithm myself.
But some parameter space descriptions imply that there is no connection between different values, like `randint` or `choice`.
If you choose one of the options, it does not impy that for the other option the loss function should somehow be similar.